# VSCode multi-root workspace: How to enable "Find All Referencess" across workspace folders for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, dependency-management

### Situation

I have a VSCode multi-root workspace with a `.code-workspace` file that looks something like this:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "name": "root",
            "path": "../"
        },
        {
            "path": "../my_backend"
        },
        {
            "path": "../my_frontend"
        },
        {
            "path": "../my_apicontract"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "files.exclude": {
            "node_modules/": true,
            "my_*/": true
        },
    }
}
```

*(The `files.exclude` is a trick I learned from https://medium.com/rewrite-tech/visual-studio-code-tips-for-monorepo-development-with-multi-root-workspaces-and-extension-6b69420ecd12#d2e4 to "de-clutter" the workspace folders, especially the root folder.)*

Each of the three `my_...` folders contains a TypeScript module. The idea of separating the API contract out into its own module is to have a "single source of truth" for the API contract between the frontend and the backend.

The `package.json` for `my_frontend` and `my_backend` each contain a `file:`-based dependency to the `my_apicontract` module:

```
  // ...
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
    "my_apicontract": "file:../my_apicontract"
  },
  // ...
```

### Need/wish

The API is expected to undergo several significant changes. These changes will obviously have an impact on both the frontend and the backend.

To make it easier to find impacted code, I was hoping that I would be able to make use of VSCode's "Find All References" functionality from within `my_apicontract` so that it shows me the code locations in both the frontend and the backend that reference the selected type/field of the API contract.

[image: Screenshot of VSCode's "Find All References" functionality]

### Complication

When using VSCode's "Find All References" functionality from within `my_apicontract`, it only finds references in `my_apicontract`. It does not find references in `my_frontend` or `my_backend`.

When using the functionality from within `my_frontend` or `my_backend`, it at least finds both references within the respective folder *and* within `my_apicontract` but also not beyond that.

### Question

How do I setup my environment in such a way that I can use the "Find All References" functionality to find references from `my_apicontract` to the frontend and backend code?

Comment: my first question is whether (if so, how) you have intellisense between workspace roots. Did you set up [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) or something?

Comment: I do have IntelliSense in both `my_backend` and `my_frontend` for the types declared in `my_apicontract` by having `my_apicontract` specified as a dependency in the backend's/frontend's `package.json`. I did not set up project references. In what folder would I need to place the "solution" `tsconfig.json` file for it to be picked up correctly?

Comment: Would workspace search (and replace) give you enough functionality to do whatever it is you're trying to do?  [Check out this comprehensive video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uc4I4ByUe0A&list=PLvKOuwv1u7bFsBC2ONDLk9LfDHklSW6xR&index=5)

Comment: Due to the nature of TypeScript where not everything has an explicit type declaration, I fear that a "more basic" search functionality will lead to too much impacted code not being found. For example, if I have `const abc = await GetFromApi();` and I'm changing the `ApiResponse` class that `GetFromApi`-returned objects have, I don't see a way to use the "workplace search" functionality here - `ApiResponse` would not even appear near the impacted code.